# How do I turn an APK into code on android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I've made many apps using a drag and drop program which just compiles the apk for you. I'm getting into programming my own apps so I want to know if it's possible to import one of my apk files into android studio so I can edit the source code myself.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to get the source code from an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file)

Comment: Have you tried usind an APK decompiler?

Comment: If you want to edit the source code, then decompling APK into code is not a good option, since it will be extracted into .class/.smali files, which is really hard to read, not to mention to edit them. I would suggest you to learn to create your desired features step by step, even from scratch if you really want to make your own app.